# How can I provide unconditional access to a Google Account?

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval, google-account, app-store-connect

As per [Apple's App Store review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/), if the app I'm making *requires* sign-in, then I must provide Apple testers with credentials.

My app exclusively uses Google Accounts, and since I am working for an organization, I am required to *only* allow accounts that are registered in the database as "students". Keep in mind when I say organization, I mean [one that is exempt from using "Sign in with Apple"](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#sign-in-with-apple).

I created a dummy Google Account to allow sign-in, and provided credentials to Apple. However, they got prompted to enter in a phone number, since their device was not recognized. What can I provide them with so that they will have **unconditional** access to my account, whether they are on a legitimate device, or a simulator behind a hundred proxies?

2FA is not enabled, nor are any recovery methods specified, so to be fully transparent I am not really sure which phone number Google seems to want. Here is the prompt Apple has got.

[image: The suspicious activity prompt]

I have already enabled the "less secure access" feature in the Google Account dashboard, but seeing as the Apple review process can be quite lengthy, I want to make sure I got this right before submitting.

Comment: As another question, since they already got the prompt and I approved the request, will they even get the prompt again? Also, if there is an alternative (I am using Google Firebase **only with** Google sign-in), that would be greatly appreciated.